# Get last insert_id in the URL in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

i have one requirement from in my application..so when ever user insert details in the requirement.and then submit..the mail will go to the particular vendor with one link..when vendor click on the link i redirect the page to login page..

So what i want to do is i want to send email link with last inserted id..

Here is my controller:

```
public function requirement()
```

{

```
  $data["msg"]="";
  $this->load->model('RequirementModel');
  $data['user']=$this->RequirementModel->getusers();
  $data['rolename']=$this->RequirementModel->getrolename();


if($this->input->post())
 {

   $this->RequirementModel->add_requirement($this->input->post());
   $all_users = $this->input->post('user_id');
   foreach($all_users as $key)
      {
         $get_email = $this->RequirementModel->get_user_email_by_id($key);
         $req_id = $this->input->post('req_id');
         $role_name = $this->input->post('role_name');
         $vacancies = $this->input->post('vacancies');
         $experience = $this->input->post('experience');
         $jd = $this->input->post('jd');
         $hiring_contact_name = $this->input->post('hiring_contact_name');
         $hiring_contact_number = $this->input->post('hiring_contact_number');
         $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
         $this->load->library('email',$config);
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
         $this->email->to($get_email); 
         $this->email->subject('this is our requirements pls go through it');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin>Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);
         print_r($get_email);
         if($this->email->send())
         {

              echo "email sent";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "email failed";
          }

}
```

}

$this->load->view('Requirements/requirements',$data);

}

Can anyone help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: is this a publicly accessible server? plz obscure your login data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the database helper function insert_id(), it returns the id of the last insert: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id

Have your add_requirement function of the RequirementModel model return the insert_id like so:

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Then just save that value when you call the function:

```
$insert_id = $this->RequirementModel->add_requirement($this->input->post());
```

Comment: i did like that in my model..how can we call that insert_id in link

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you want to put it in the link, but I'm guessing something like this could be ok: 
`$link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin' . $insert_id . '>Click Here</a>';` I do see you are missing a second " though.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean the signin() function isn't working? What error does it give?